# How to create a matrix from a vector

Tags: r

I have a matrix mydata. I take it's eigen

```
ev <- eigen(mydata)

               [,1]                    [,2]                    [,3]                    [,4]                    [,5]            [,6]
[1,] -0.44852453+0i  0.11670674-0.43102606i  0.11670674+0.43102606i  0.02678808-0.00239041i  0.02678808+0.00239041i  0.013711630+0i
[2,] -0.40701659+0i  0.17265390+0.01329737i  0.17265390-0.01329737i  0.32050237+0.31677316i  0.32050237-0.31677316i -0.946287625+0i
[3,] -0.65381971+0i  0.35662142+0.31807798i  0.35662142-0.31807798i -0.83423480+0.00000000i -0.83423480+0.00000000i -0.265152784+0i
[4,] -0.37545331+0i -0.72987261+0.00000000i -0.72987261+0.00000000i -0.00637960-0.10181135i -0.00637960+0.10181135i  0.004667737+0i
[5,] -0.05763717+0i  0.02473111+0.01282302i  0.02473111-0.01282302i -0.00818839+0.03180396i -0.00818839-0.03180396i  0.122647730+0i
[6,] -0.24778175+0i
```

Just in case the result is not sorted, I get the maximal eigenvector corresponding to the maximal eigenvalue thus:

```
k <- which(abs(ev$values)==max(abs(ev$values)))
G<-ev$vectors[,k]

[1] -0.44852453+0i -0.40701659+0i -0.65381971+0i -0.37545331+0i -0.05763717+0i -0.24778175+0i
```

Call this maximal eigenvector

G = [g
1
, g
2
...g
n
]
T

So in this case G = [-0.44852453+0i -0.40701659+0i -0.65381971+0i -0.37545331+0i -0.05763717+0i -0.24778175+0i with n=6

**My question is, I want to build a matrix of ratios from this eigenvector, so that 
B={bij = gi / gj}. Is there a function in R that does this? If not what is the cleanest way to get the matrix without looping?** {sorry I don't know how to show the mathematical notation in this interface. That should read, the matrix B = entry b(sub ij) = g(sub i) / g(sub j), g is a member of G }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is unrelated to eigenvalues and that you simply want to create a matrix `B` from a vector, where `B[i,j]` = `G[i]/G[j]` for the vector `G`.

This can be achieved with the `outer` function, which produces the outer product but lets you specify the function.

```
G <- 1:4
outer(G, G, FUN='/')
##      [,1] [,2]      [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1  0.5 0.3333333 0.25
## [2,]    2  1.0 0.6666667 0.50
## [3,]    3  1.5 1.0000000 0.75
## [4,]    4  2.0 1.3333333 1.00
```

Comment: Sorry that is not correct. For example, the matrix is 6x6. The diagonal entries are clearly all 1. [1,2] = -0.44852453 / -0.40701659 = 1.101980954. [2,1] = -0.40701659 / -0.44852453 = 0.9074567 [5,4] = -0.05763717 / -0.37545331 =  0.153513549 and so on.

Comment: This result is not using your input vector, so of course the values are not correct!  Try applying `outer` as shown, to your actual vector.